# What is the purpose of a Money Mortgage Deed of Trust Affidavit?

Tags: united-states, real-estate

I'm recently divorced and in the process of closing on a house, and was given the option by the title company of either having my ex sign a Subordination of Child Support Lien *or* executing a Money Mortgage Deed of Trust Affidavit (which apparently would automatically subordinate the Child Support Lien by Nebraska state law).

I read a couple sample affidavits I found online, and all of them basically just state that all proceeds of the loan were used for the property purchase. I understand the lien process, but it isn't clear as what the difference between signing the affidavit and obtaining an explicit lien subordination is. Would subsequent transactions (selling the house, or taking a home equity loan) be effected differently based on which route I go? My understanding is that in any case, I would have to have the Child Support Lien re-subordinated for new financing or released for a sale.